# Issue with image inside div - (Grid in Tailwind CSS)

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Sorry if you find this question silly, But I'm new to Tailwind CSS.

So below is my html with Tailwind CSS classes added.

```html
<div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 py-5">
  <div class="grid gap-6 grid-cols-3 ">
    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-2 rounded-lg bg-black">
      <img alt="Swimming Pool" src="...." class="rounded-lg" />
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-lg bg-sky-500/100">
      <img alt="Swimming Pool" src="...." class="rounded-lg" />
    </div>
    <div class=" rounded-lg  bg-sky-500/100">
      <img alt="Swimming Pool" src="...." class="rounded-lg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm using CDN at the moment, Below is my head section code

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com?plugins=forms,typography,aspect-ratio,line-clamp"></script>
</head>
```

**Issue :** I want first image to be aligned vertically with other images, I found the issue is because of "gap-6", If I remove gap images are aligned properly.
Also I'm using "rounded-lg" class for both div and img is it correct?  or is there any other alternative to it?

Can someone please help me?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider filling the parent element with the `<img>` by applying `width: 100%; height: 100%`. This will make the image distorted, so you may wish to also apply `object-fit: cover` to the `<img>` too to prevent the distortion.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="mx-auto max-w-7xl px-2 py-5">
  <div class="grid gap-6 grid-cols-3 ">
    <div class="col-span-2 row-span-2 rounded-lg bg-black">
      <img alt="Swimming Pool" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/500" class="rounded-lg w-full h-full object-cover" />
    </div>
    <div class="rounded-lg bg-sky-500/100">
      <img alt="Swimming Pool" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1000" class="rounded-lg" />
    </div>
    <div class=" rounded-lg  bg-sky-500/100">
      <img alt="Swimming Pool" src="https://picsum.photos/1000/1500" class="rounded-lg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works,  Thank you. I believe it was because of the height of the image? Is the "rounded-lg" for both div and image is alright?

Comment: It is partly due to the height of the image. `rounded-lg` for both the `<div>` and image is alright. You could consider applying `overflow: hidden` via the `overflow-hidden` class to the `<div>` elements so that you don't need `rounded-lg` on the `<img>` elements.